# jQuery calling WCF service

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I am in the process of implementing jQuery calling WCF service which is hosted in the same domain.

My application uses Win Auth that works fine with ASP.NET app. I would like to know from the team if the user calls the WCF service from the ASP.NET what is the security context in which the service runs? Or it uses the web.config security which is specified? Are there any links related to this where i can get some information.

ASP.NET 4.0, jQuery and WCF 4.0 in same web application

Answer (score 2):

Here are two links from Pablo Cibraro which should help:

Security Identity propagation for WCF Ajax endpoints in ASP.NET
http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/10/21/security-identity-propagation-for-wcf-ajax-endpoints-in-asp-net.aspx

Sharing the security context between ASP.NET and WCF REST Services
http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/04/08/sharing-the-security-context-between-asp-net-and-wcf-rest-services.aspx

As an aside, it's probably a good idea to go through some of your 42 questions without accepted answers, and accept some - you may find you get a quicker response to future questions ;)